# How to use highchart pattern fill in angular?

Tags: highcharts, angular6

I have been searching the internet about how to add highchart patternfill in angular highcharts, but no results have been found for angular. Is there any plugin available for angular or anybody have used this in angular application? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import and initialize the `pattern-fill` module:

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as patternFill from "highcharts/modules/pattern-fill";

patternFill(Highcharts);
```

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/18xojqn50j

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/blob/master/README.md#to-load-a-module