# Getting error while using pattern in Angular Highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts

I want proper documentation for Angular-Highcharts for pattern fill. Whenever I'm using below code I'm getting error on patter attribute. I even tried below link but it did not solve my problem.

[How to use highchart pattern fill in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795479/how-to-use-highchart-pattern-fill-in-angular)

```
series: [
{
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Total Revenue',
  color: {
    pattern: {
      path: {
        d: 'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11',
        strokeWidth: 3
      },
      width: 10,
      height: 10,
      opacity: 0.4
    }
  },
  data: [],
  id: 'revenueTrends',
  showInLegend: false
},
{
  type: 'line',
  name: 'Rolling year average',
  data: [],
  id: 'rollingYearAvg',
  color: '#002750',
  lineWidth: 1,
  label: {
    enabled: false
  },
  marker: {
    radius: 5
  },
  showInLegend: true
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread that you are referring to is related to the `highcharts-angular` not `angular-highcharts` (the difference is that the first one is the official wrapper, the second is a 3rd party product), so I am assuming that you are asking about the `highcharts-angular` way.

The error that you are getting is probably related to the typescript - your pattern option object was lacking a few required properties. To fix it you could add all of them, or if you are sure that they are not necessary, and the chart will work correctly without them cast the entire object to `as unknown as Highcharts.PatternObject`

```js
   series: [
      {
        type: "column",
        name: "Total Revenue",
        color: {
          pattern: {
            path: {
              d: "M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11",
              strokeWidth: 3
            },
            width: 10,
            height: 10,
            opacity: 0.4
          }
        } as unknown as Highcharts.PatternObject,
        data: [1, 2, 3],
        id: "revenueTrends",
        showInLegend: false
      }
    ]
```

**API references:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.PatternOptionsObject

**Live demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-7bxgyt

You can find more information about using the `highcharts-angular` wrapper on its GitHub repository, here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Comment: Great! It did worked out with above solution. Also where can I find different patterns examples?

Comment: Without `strokeWidth` it's very thin, hence to add a `strokeWidth` what I can do?

Comment: It seems that I was wrong - I updated my answer and the demo. The `strokeWidth` property is a valid property of the `path` (`Highcharts. SVGAttributes`). https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGAttributes